# How to use Glide's SimpleTarget with databinding?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-databinding

I use Glide to load my image. I need to modify my image with a SimpleTarget callback, however when the image loaded to my list, and I scroll the list shows first always an other image, and than animate the right image after 1 second to the place. Without image modification and SimpleTarget everything works just fine. Here is my code.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageSrc")
public static void setImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {

    Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
           //the bitmap modified here
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    });
}
```

is there any solution to avoid the flickering?

Comment: put your databinding code here

Comment: I believe there is not so much to do with the databinding code, because without the SimpleTarget callback everything works just fine.

Comment: is an issue in your adapter, can  you put it here?